# How would I go about getting a vector3 of a random position somewhere on top of another gameObject?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I need to get a Vector3 of a random position ontop of another gameobject. This gameobject will always be rectangular but may vary in size throughout (and others within the game will also be different and may need to use the same function).

Since the size will vary I cant rely on using numbers I input before hand and need to code something which will generate a random Transform.Position within the the space the gameobject takes up.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be very grateful!

Comment: How do you know the size of the gameobject? Is it a mesh?

Comment: Yes it has a mesh filter and mesh renderer

Comment: Should the point be on top along the world axis or the local axis?

Comment: world axis is preferred

Comment: Is the GameObject always upright?

Comment: Yes it doesn't rotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the mesh bounds to clamp the range of your random generator. You also need to either transform the point to world space if you want to use it for something that won't be a child of the object below.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GetRandomPos : MonoBehaviour {
    private Mesh mesh;
    public float y_amount = 1;

    private void Awake()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    }

    public Vector3 GetRandomPointAbove()
    {
        float minx = mesh.bounds.min.x;
        float minz = mesh.bounds.min.z;
        float maxx = mesh.bounds.max.x;
        float maxz = mesh.bounds.max.z;
        float x = Random.Range(minx, maxx);
        float y = y_amount;
        float z = Random.Range(minz, maxz);
        var localPos = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        return transform.TransformPoint(localPos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow that looks to be exactly what I was looking for! Thanks so much! 

If you dont mind could you re-explain that second part about transforming the point to world space? I have tried this code and the postions it returns are slightly off the object which clearly means I need to use what you are speaking off I just dont quite understand what you mean

Comment: Slightly off in what way? The transforming to world space is because the point you generate from the mesh bounds is in local space, and doesn't include the offset, scale, or rotation of the parent transform

Comment: Turns out it was because a bunch of my prefabs were not set to 0 haha!

Thank you so much for the help!